# How to align font-awesome icon vertically

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using font-awesome for battery but it is aligned horizontally. I need it vertically. I can i get it.

M using this

```
<i class="fa fa-battery-full" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Actual Result

[image]

This is the expected Result
[image]

Comment: Use fa-rotate-{degree} according font awesome

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.fa.fa-battery-full {    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-battery-full" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using native font-awesome classes from the [documentation](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#rotated-flipped)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-battery-full fa-rotate-270" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

- `fa-rotate-90`
- `fa-rotate-180`
- `fa-rotate-270`
- `fa-flip-horizontal`
- `fa-flip-vertical`

Comment: This is the best one, will delete mine as I forgot that they have something like this x)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this 2 ways: using the FA classes or by adding some transformation styles to the  tag or adding another class with the following styles.

To use FA classes use the class 'fa-rotate-270' to rotate your icon 270 degrees clockwise:

```
<i class="fa fa-battery-full fa-rotate-270"/></i>
```

The above rotaion supports rotation steps of '90' '180' and '270' only.

If you wanted to apply a transformation instead (potentially you could customise further this way) your code would look like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-battery-full" style="transform: rotate(-90deg);" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Also please note that the following are cross browser compatible versions of the transformation if you want to ensure compatibility.

```
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

use css property`transform: rotate(-90deg);`, `.fa-battery-full{ transform: rotate(-90deg);}`.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to rotate the icon.

```css
.fa.fa-battery-full { transform: rotate(270deg); }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-battery-full" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
 $(function(){
     $('.fa.fa-battery-full').css({"transform": "rotate("+-90+"deg)"});
  });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrtr7gwn/)